# How do I make lenses from a record in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, template-haskell, haskell-lens

I want to play around with the `Lens` library a bit.  I've loaded it into GHCi and created a record data type with the appropriate underscores:

```
> data Foo a = Foo {_arg1 :: Int, _arg2 :: [a]}
```

I would like to make the lenses for `Foo` using the `makeLenses` template.  I would like to do this without needing to read through the entire set of [Template-Haskell docs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell).

What incantation can I type in at the GHCi prompt to get this to work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tested in GHCi 7.8.3:

```
:set -XTemplateHaskell
:m +Control.Lens
:{
data AST = AInt  { _aid :: Int, _ival :: Int }
         | AChar { _aid :: Int, _cval :: Char }
         deriving (Show)
makeLenses ''AST
:}
```

(I believe that the `:{ ... :}` block is necessary for `makeLenses` to work).

Let's briefly check:

```
λ >> AChar 100 'f' ^. aid
100
λ >> AChar 100 'f' ^? cval
Just 'f'
λ >> AInt 101 0 ^? cval
Nothing
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the `makeLenses` call has to go in the *same* `:{` block as the data declaration! That threw me for a loop until I figured it out.

Comment: It's enough to have _any_ statement in the :{ block together with `makeLenses`, (it does not have to be the AST declaration). As far as I understand, then ghci will expand the `makeLenses` as declaration list. If there is only one statement in :{ block, then it tries to expand it as expression, giving type mismatch error.